# How do you use simple exponential smoothing in R?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I'm beginner in R, Could you please explain how to use ses in forecast package of R [forecast](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/forecast.pdf)?
I'd like to choose the number of initial periods and smoothing constant.

```
d <- c(3,4,41,10,9,86,56,20,18,36,24,59,82,51,31,29,13,7,26,19,20,103,141,145,24,99,40,51,72,58,94,78,11,15,17,53,44,34,12,15,32,14,15,26,75,110,56,43,19,17,33,26,40,42,18,24,69,18,18,25,86,106,104,35,43,12,4,20,16,8)
```

I have 70 periods, I'd like to use 40 Periods for initial and 30 for out-of sample.

```
ses(d, h=30, level=c(80,95), fan=FALSE,initial=c("simple"), alpha=.1)
```

Is it correct?

Comment: I've assumed the function your referring to is in the forecast package - if that is incorrect please specify what package the function is located in.

Comment: Yst that is ses in the forecast package

Comment: There are a few examples here: https://www.otexts.org/fpp/7/1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will do it:

```
ses(d[1:40], h=30, alpha=0.1, initial="simple")
```

with:

- `h` being the number of periods for forecasting.
- `alpha` being the level smoothing parameter.
- `initial` being the method for selecting initial state values

(See `?ses`.)

Comment: What is the difference between `ses` and `ets` functions ? Is there one that is better ?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the HoltWinters function, which is available in base R:

```
mod1 <- HoltWinters(d[1:40], alpha=0.1, beta=FALSE, gamma=FALSE)
```

To obtain the predictions for the next 30 periods,  use

```
predict(mod1, n.ahead=30)
```